# Create partition to existing physical column in HIVE

Tags: hive

Is it possible to create a table with partition column as one of the table columns in HIVE?

for ex: create table test (a int, b string, c int) partitioned by (c int)

when running the above it gets this error "Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10035]: Column repeated in partitioning columns"

Answer (score 0):

Its possible and You are almost correct. Correct syntax is -

```
create table test (a int, b string) partitioned by (c int)
```